# Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm making an API with Express.js and Sequelize for an appointment scheduling app. So far I have two models, User and Salon, with an N:M relationship. (So an user might manage many salons, for a franchise for example, or a salon may be managed by many employees)

I have stumbled upon a problem in the `PUT /salons` route. My intention is that the user can fill out a form to input the details of the salon, and then the logged in user will be associated with this salon.

The code for the route looks like this:

```js
router.put('/', checkLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  const user = User.findOne({ where: { id: req.user.id } })
    .then(() =>
      Salon.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        street: req.body.street,
        number: req.body.number,
        zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
        town: req.body.town,
        province: req.body.province,
        addressComplements: req.body.addressComplements,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      })
    )
    .then((salon) => salon.addUser(req.user.id))
    .then((salon) => res.status(200).json(salon))
    .catch((err) => next(new Error(err)))
})
```

When testing with Postman, serverside I get this query log:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "firstName", "lastName", "isActive", "password", "confirmationCode", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = 1;
ERROR PUT /salons Error: Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value
    at /home/elviraramirez/Sandbox/hair-and-now-redux/hair-and-now-redux-server/routes/salons.routes.js:31:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
PUT /salons 500 80.416 ms - 39
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing things wrong, as that look pretty... defined to me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check if `req.user.id` has value

Comment: And there was the problem. It did return `undefined`, but it worked if I requested that ID thus: `req.user[0].id`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the case all your code is correct, but the only thing we have to do is to include one input type which is hidden and which further containd the ID of that product like this:

`<input type= "hidden" name="produçtId" value="<% product.id %>" >`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while working on a route and I tried to use the parser middleware before the route declaration part like this

```js
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const placesRouter = express.Router()
```

but it didn't work for me, until i add the configuration to the route instead :

```js
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json())
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Nembie. I got the same error `WHERE parameter "module" has invalid "undefined" value` but with the case that was different and tried to fix the following.

I have a API with request method `GET` with route `/salons?module=coin`

To get a value(or **coin**) from the request that I use:

```
let module = req.params.module
```

Fix to:

```
let module = req.input.get.module
```

or:

```
let module = req.query.module
```